# What is a sumset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have sets $X = \{0,2,3\}$ and $Y = \{1,2,5\}$.

Is the sumset defined to be

$X + Y = \{0 + 1,2 +2,3+5\} =  \{1,4,8\}$

or summing every element pairwise

$X + Y = \{1,2,5,3,4,7,8\} $

?

Answer (score 4):

$$ A + B = \{a+b : a \in A, b \in B\}. $$
If $X = \{0,2,3\}$ and $Y = \{1,2,5\}$.
$$X+Y=\{0+1;0+2;0+5;2+1;2+2;2+5;3+1;3+2;3+5\}$$